# How to add my own images to the views slide show?

Tags: views

I am new to Drupal. I have been trying to make a slide show on the front page but I am facing an issue on how to upload images of my choice in the slide show. I.e. the images that I have in my computers folder.

I have created a view and placed an image field in it, everything is set. I have also added the block to the main page content. All I can see on the front page is the slider title obviously since i have not been able to add any images.

Can any body tell me how to set my own images to the slider?

I don't want to use fixer slider.

I have used views slide show and some other js files for cycle.

**Edit**: Here is a screenprint of the view I defiined so far:

[image]

Comment: Attach a picture of your view implementation , (do you have assigned a content type for your slider?)

Comment: Edit or create a new node and just upload the image(s) to your image field.

Answer (score 3):

First you need create a content type for your slider (`admin/structure/types/add`), let alias it `slider`, then add your desire fields to it ( maybe a image field and title as a slider slogan ), then create a image style for your slider in `admin/config/media/image-styles/add` ( create a image style according to your slider image in your design), then   in views  change filter to show only images form slider content type.

For more details do  "[How to Build Drupal 8 Slideshows](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drupal-8-slideshows/)" step by step.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have now created a view for your slider , what it does is that when a new article is posted in your site this view fetches article's image out of it and shows it on your slideshow , so an answer for your question is : "create some articles and views will use their images for your slider"

Now the problem is whenever a new article is posted to your site slider image changes , I mean this content type is not exclusive for slider (or it can be if you don't use it for posting articles), to overcome this problem you can follow Zhilevan's instruction to create an exclusive content type for your slider.

you also can use [Nivo Slider](https://www.drupal.org/project/nivo_slider) if you want a fast solution for that. (off course it's not as dynamic and configurable as views slideshow)

Comment: vote up , this is good solution, I think using Nivo Slider is better solution instead of views_slideshow

Comment: @zhilevan thanks for vote up DADASH. I really enjoyed using Nivo Slider , easy to use and not much overhead for system. and slides can be rearranged without need for sorting options.

Answer (score 1):

> I have created a view and placed an image field in it...

Suitably configured, *Views Slideshow* will display images selected by the related *View*. Depending on how that View is configured, you may need to create some content of a particular *content-type*, or content which meets some other criteria which you defined in the View.

For example: maybe you set the View to filter content on *promoted to front page*. In that case, you will need to make sure that the nodes which you create to hold related images all have the *promoted to front page* option switched on.

Suggestion: Make a copy of the View, or add a *display* to it. There, set the *Format* to some simple option such as *Unformatted list*. Then check that the View displays the expected content. This will help to isolate where the problem is by removing *Views Slideshow* from the equation.